# WPF Autocompletebox WCF Service

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, wcf, autocomplete

Actually im developing an WPF Application. This App has an AutoCompleteBox which i want to connect with a WCF Service Method.

The WCF Service returns adresses and street names.

```
<input:AutoCompleteBox IsTextCompletionEnabled="False" KeyUp="AutoCompleteBox_KeyUp" ></input:AutoCompleteBox>
```

I want to start searching via the WCF Service if i entered more than 3 characters, because of the data size.

```
private async void AutoCompleteBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        AutoCompleteBox input = (AutoCompleteBox)sender;
        input.ItemsSource = null;

        if(e.Key == Key.Back)
        {
            if (input.Text.Length >= 3)
            {
                await FillAutoCompleteBox(input);
            }
        }

        if (input.Text.Length >= 3)
        {
            await FillAutoCompleteBox(input);
        }
    }

private async Task FillAutoCompleteBox(AutoCompleteBox input)
    {
        WCFService.DataServiceClient client = new WCFService.DataServiceClient();
        List<string> list= new List<string>();

        foreach (var result in client.GetStreets(input.Text))
        {
            suggestedList.Add(result.Name);
        }

        input.ItemsSource = suggestedList;
    }
```

It works but its really slowly because they are a lot of suggested streets. 
Example type: 'roa..'

Comment: Hi, what is your question?

Comment: The AutoCompleteBox is very slowly and when i type for example 'roa' and after the 3 character the service finds 100 entries then the autocomplete box is very slowly. what i can do to solve this?

Comment: First isolate the problem. Is WPF slow? Is the WCF connection slow? Is the database slow? If you are targetting a remote server you could use `Fiddler` to capture the raw WCF request.